# Properties vs Categories on an Aspect in Alfresco

Tags: solr, alfresco

I'm using Alfresco 4.1.6 and Solr 1.4.

I'm reading about the possibility of using classifications for the nodes, specified with a type d:category in an aspect on the content model.

A good time of searchs in our project are the most important, is the reason I try to design the best option possible for this. Our repository have over 2 millions of documents, spread over directories, where each user (we have 3000 users aprox) have an own root path.

For the queries (FTS_ALFRESCO), we actually use TYPE (we have 5 distinct types of nodes defined on our model) and custom properties (all of them that we use in the queries are indexed).

My question is... Imagine I change my model and use one of our properties like a category. I delete a property and create an aspect with d:category with this property. The search will be more efficient and quickly if I search by TYPE, property and category? Alfresco gives me a best performance if I search this value like a category instead of when I search this value like a normal indexed property? Or really is the same? Whats the benefits of use this like a category?

Answer (score 0):

Category and Properties both of them has different usage.

Main difference is

**Property**:You could have different value of same property for each content

**Category**:You will have same category which can be associated to muliple contents

So, based on your requirement you have to choose which one you want to use. As far as performence is concerned I guess category based search will be faster(I haven't really tried it though).